# Is it possible to find such a function?

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

The subset S of $\mathbb{R}^2$ is defined by $S=\{(x,f(x))\}$, where $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ is defined everywhere but not continuous on $\mathbb{R}$. Is it possible to find such a function $f$ to make $S$ a closed set?  I'm thinking about $f(x)=\sin\frac{1}{x}$ for $x \not=0$; $f(x)=0$ for $x =0$, but not sure about if this makes S closed...

Comment: The function in your question is *not* a counterexample: e.g. $(0, 1)$ is in the closure of the graph (consider the sequence of points $x_n={2\over {(4n+1)\pi}})$, but not the graph, so its graph is not closed.

Answer (score 3):

In general, yes, there are counterexamples: consider $f(x)={1\over x}$ for $x\not=0$, and $f(0)=0$.

---

However, a **bounded** function is continuous if and only if its graph is closed.

To see this, first let's show the following slightly weaker statement:

> If the graph of $f$ is closed, and $\lim_{x\rightarrow a}f(x)$ exists and equals $L$, then $f(a)=L$.

Proof: If $\lim_{x\rightarrow a}f(x)=L$, then we can find a sequence of points $(x_n, f(x_n))$ which approach $(a, L)$. But then since the graph of $f$ is closed, this means that $(a, L)$ is in the graph of $f$, that is, $f(a)=L$. $\Box$

Now the more general result:

> Suppose $f(x)$ is defined everywhere on $\mathbb{R}$, and bounded: $f(x)\in [-b, b]$ for some $a>0$. Then $f$ is continuous iff the graph of $f$ is closed.

Proof: Fix $a\in\mathbb{R}$, and look at the lim sup of $f(x)$ as $x$ approaches $a$ from the left (say). This exists and is finite (say, equals $L_{+, left}$), since $f$ is bounded; we get a sequence $(x_n, f(x_n))$ approaching $(a, L_{+, left})$. Since the graph of $f$ is closed, this means $f(a)=L_{+, left}$. Similarly, $f(a)$ is the lim inf from the left, and the lim inf and lim sup from the right; so $f(a)=\lim_{x\rightarrow a}f(x)$, and $f$ is continuous. $\Box$

*Note that we've crucially used the fact that e.g. $\lim\sup_{x\rightarrow a^+}f(x)\in\mathbb{R}$; if $f$ is not bounded, this breaks down, and this is exactly what lets our counterexample above work!*

Actually, we've proved something slightly stronger:

> Suppose $f$ is defined everywhere on $\mathbb{R}$, and is **locally bounded** [= for every $a$, there are $\delta, \epsilon>0$ such that for all $x\in (a-\delta, a+\delta)$ we have $f(x)\in (f(a)-\epsilon, f(a)+\epsilon)]$. Then $f$ is continuous iff the graph of $f$ is closed.

Comment: I'm convinced by your proof below but don't quite get why the function "$f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$ for $x \not= 0$ and $f(0)=0$" makes the set S closed.

Comment: OK, so start by getting rid of the origin - do you see why the set $X=\{(x, {1\over x}): x\in\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}\}$ is a closed subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$? If so, then note that certainly the origin $\{(0, 0)\}$ is closed, so the graph of this $f$ is just the union of two closed sets - and so, closed.

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks!